# error: invalid operands of types 'const char[8]' and 'const char [17]' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++

The compiler isn't like my last std::cout line. I commented to specify where the error is occurring. I would love to hear some feedback on this. Thanks in advance.

In addition, I would like, if you please, some general comments on my adherence to C++ coding practice and my contains repeats algorithm. I know that it's useless having that bool as the value in my std::map, but it's not possible to map a 1-dimensional map like std::map. Gotta add a value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void print_vector(std::vector<int>); 
bool contains_repeats_1(std::vector<int>);

int main() { 

    int arr1[] = {1, 5, 4, 3, -8, 3, 90, -300, 5, 69, 10};
    std::vector<int> vec1(arr1, arr1 + sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int));
    std::cout << "vec1 =" << std::endl;
    print_vector(vec1); 
    int arr2[] =  {1, 6, 7, 89, 69, 23, 19, 100, 8, 2, 50, 3, 11, 90};              
    std::vector<int> vec2(arr2, arr2 + sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int));
    std::cout << "vec2 =" << std::endl;
    print_vector(vec2);
    std::cout << "vec1 " << contains_repeats_1(vec1) ? "does" : "doesn't" << " contain repeats" << std::endl;
        // ^^^^^^ ERROR

    return 0;

} 

void print_vector(std::vector<int> V) { 
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = V.begin(); 
    std::cout << "{" << *it;
    while (++it != V.end())
        std::cout << ", " << *it;
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;  
}


bool contains_repeats_1(std::vector<int> V) { 
    std::map<int,bool> M;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = V.begin(); it != V.end(); it++) {
        if (M.count(*it) == 0) { 
            M.insert(std::pair<int,bool>(*it, true));
        } else {
            return true;         
        }
        return false; 
    }

}
```

Comment: surround `contains_repeats_1(vec1) ? "does" : "doesn't"` in brackets `()`.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator `?:` has a fairly low precedence (lower than `<<`), so you need to add parenthesis.

```
std::cout << "vec1 " << (contains_repeats_1(vec1) ? "does" : "doesn't") << " contain repeats" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<` has higher precedence than `?:`

```
std::cout << "vec1 " << (contains_repeats_1(vec1) ? "does" : "doesn't") << " contain repeats" << std::endl;
```